# Does Laravel's Request object have any default field 'title'?

Tags: php, laravel

In our api when we update a group we send the request in following way

```
{
  "title" : "test",
  "description" : "test description",
  "date_time" : 45525465,
  "interest" : "1",
  "age_group" : [3],
  "capacity" : "10",
  "ethnicity" : [],
  "privacy_type" : "1",     
}
```

There are several other key-value pairs. By default only those fields are updated which are provided in the request. For example if i want to update only `privacy_type` I only need to send

```
{
    "privacy_type" : "2"
}
```

The problem is that when I try to update `privacy_type` like this, `title` is also being updated with the value of the `route`. If I do `dd($request->input('title')` , I get `"api/v1/groups/10024"` which is the route for updating a group. Changing `title` to `group_title` is an option, but I would like to know if there is any other option. Thanks

Comment: Please show us your controller code.

Comment: Controller code has nothing to do with my problem. I am getting an extra field in the request even though i don't send it. 
`$group->group_title = $request->title ?? $group->group_title;` anyway, this is the portion responsible for updating group title

Answer (score 1):

You just need a proper ternary:

```
$group->group_title = $request->has('title') ? $request->get('title') : $group->group_title;
```

Comment: i did this `$request->has('title') ? dd($request->get('title')) : '';` and still got the same result.

Comment: You can write it as `$group->group_title = $request->get('title') ?: $group->group_title;`